# How do I sort by the last letter of a value in a dictionay in python?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

given the following list of dictionaries, how do I sort by **the last letter of the name**?

```
    list_of_dicts = [
    {'name': 'Jadis', 'year_of_birth': 0, 'gender': 'Female'},
    {'name': 'Peter', 'year_of_birth': 1927, 'gender': 'Male'},
    {'name': 'Susan', 'year_of_birth': 1928, 'gender': 'Female'},
    {'name': 'Edmund', 'year_of_birth': 1930, 'gender': 'Male'},
    {'name': 'Lucy', 'year_of_birth': 1932, 'gender': 'Female'}]
```

Comment: I guess you may need a python tag for better visibility?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the built-in function `sorted(yourlist=, key=)`.

Where `your_list` is your `list_of_dicts` and with `key=` you define the logic how you want your input list to be sorted. In your case, the code is:

```
sorted_list=sorted(list_of_dicts, key=lambda x: x['name'][-1])
```

The lambda function allows you to sort the last character of `x['name']` for every `x` inside your original list.
It returns when `print (sorted_list)`:

```
[{'name': 'Edmund', 'year_of_birth': 1930, 'gender': 'Male'}, {'name': 
'Susan', 'year_of_birth': 1928, 'gender': 'Female'}, {'name': 'Peter', 
'year_of_birth': 1927, 'gender': 'Male'}, {'name': 'Jadis', 'year_of_birth': 
0, 'gender': 'Female'}, {'name': 'Lucy', 'year_of_birth': 1932, 'gender': 
'Female'}]
```

As you can see, the sorted list follows 'Edmund'->'Susan'->'Peter'->'Jadis'->'Lucy'

Answer (score 0):

> In case, you want to sort the same list (in place), you can use "`.sort`" method on the list.

```
list_of_dicts.sort(key= lambda x: x.get('name')[-1]) # key accepts a function, and we are fetching the last letter of the name. 
print (list_of_dicts)
```

> I hope this helps and counts.